# jQuery mobile and text input for currency (euro)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery Mobile, I need a text input for Money (Euro) so that can accept only number with some masking.

Any idea how to do it using the framework or HTML5? thanks!

Comment: That seems a bit broad. (especially the masking part)

Comment: I think you'll need to check whether or not your input follows a certain regexp pattern, while the user is typing :S...

Comment: Try one of those jQuery plugins ? [http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-currencyprice-plugins/](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-currencyprice-plugins/)

Comment: You can try this plugin here: https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney
I've never used this with the jQuery-mobile, but already used in many web applications, let me know if it works with jquery-Mobile. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, you can try the Jquery MaskMoney.

I've never used this with the jQuery-mobile, but by your comment it works fine.

The plugin Link: [JQuery MaskMoney](http://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney)